# Building projects from source - determining / changing bin location?

Tags: linux, ansible, source, make

I have pulled down a git repository for Ansible and followed the instructions to build it. I'm not familiar with the process of building from source and am somewhat confused.

http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_installation.html

When everything was completed ansible successfully ran. However, it did not create the usual config directory `/etc/ansible` and running `which ansible` produces `/home/testuser/ansible/bin/`

Does it seem odd that the binary is located here ? Did I do this incorrectly ? How can I install or Move this safely to `/usr/bin` or `/usr/local/bin` ?

Comment: Why do you think you need to do this? Just install from your distro's repo or from pypi.

Comment: yes, but I'm testing ansible 2.0 which is in alpha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> running `which ansible` produces `/home/testuser/ansible/bin/`

That's ok.

[env-setup](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/hacking/env-setup) changes some environment variables. For example, [`PATH`](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/a431121f9f14375d5f9d9795072dacda0fddddba/hacking/env-setup#L35):

```
expr "$PATH" : "${PREFIX_PATH}.*" > /dev/null || export PATH="$PREFIX_PATH:$PATH"
```

> it did not create the usual config directory `/etc/ansible`

That's ok.

Ansible doesn't create the directory `/etc/ansible`.

The directory `/etc/ansible` comes with package.

For example, the [Debian package](https://salsa.debian.org/debian/ansible/tree/master/debian) contains:

- [debian/ansible.dirs](https://salsa.debian.org/debian/ansible/blob/master/debian/ansible.dirs) with `etc/ansible`
- [debian/ansible.install](https://salsa.debian.org/debian/ansible/blob/master/debian/ansible.install) with

  ```
  debian/conf/hosts etc/ansible
  examples/ansible.cfg etc/ansible
  ```

Comment: @rreeves :) bonus: [Why not use “which”? What to use then?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85249/why-not-use-which-what-to-use-then) :)